# CSS grid uses unnecessary space

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to do some sort of timeline design using CSS grid, with elements interweaved on both sides. But at least rows 1, 2 and the last have juste blanked unused space.

The columns are declared, but the rows aren't. So I tried using `grid-auto-rows: min-content`, but it didn't change anything. Actually, whatever the value I put doesn't change anything. I tried putting hardcoded px value (which is not a option) for testing, and I can easily keep the integrity of the design without the dead space.

Tested on Firefox and Brave

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  font-size: 1px;
}

body {
  font-size: 16rem;
}


/*******/

.wrapper {
  --border-width: 0.5em;
  --gap: 8rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: var(--gap);
  padding: 0.5em;
  align-items: start;
}

h2 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  font-size: 2em;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  text-align: justify;
  border-top: var(--border-width) solid var(--accent);
  border-bottom: var(--border-width) solid transparent;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  max-width: 60ch;
}

section::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: var(--border-width);
  width: calc(var(--border-width) + var(--gap));
  background-color: var(--accent);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--border-width));
  z-index: -1;
}

section:nth-of-type(odd) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  border-right: var(--border-width) solid var(--accent);
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
}

section:nth-of-type(odd)::after {
  left: 0;
  translate: -100%;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  justify-self: end;
  border-left: var(--border-width) solid var(--accent);
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
}

section:nth-of-type(even)::after {
  right: 0;
  translate: 100%;
}

.date {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12rem;
  padding: 0.6em 0.3em;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  background-color: var(--accent);
  color: white;
}

.date:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border-radius: 1em 0 1em 0;
}

.date:nth-of-type(even) {
  border-radius: 0 1em 0 1em;
}

.date>* {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.green {
  --accent: hsl(171, 67%, 28%);
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.orange {
  --accent: hsl(22, 99%, 50%);
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.orange.date {
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.yellow {
  --accent: hsl(46, 100%, 47%);
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.yellow.date {
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.pink {
  --accent: hsl(343, 78%, 62%);
  grid-row: 4/6;
}

.pink.date {
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.blue {
  --accent: hsl(192deg 80% 48%);
  grid-row: 5/7;
}

.blue.date {
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>

  <section class="green">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus quidem qui, aliquid asperiores commodi officiis inventore laboriosam dignissimos dolor officia id itaque tempora provident exercitationem accusamus expedita ullam dolorum fuga. Officiis temporibus
    porro nesciunt libero, eum aliquid doloremque minima nisi sint minus id mollitia ea quisquam consequuntur laudantium autem. Aperiam.
  </section>
  <p class="green date"><span>03/2022</span>-<span>04/2023</span></p>

  <section class="orange">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, quisquam atque. Dolores beatae, nisi, laborum perspiciatis architecto non dolorem quae, doloribus aliquam quaerat rem? Esse hic illum sint mollitia quibusdam repellendus totam dolorum voluptatem
    ipsa, nobis sapiente. Quasi quo porro aperiam cumque nobis debitis praesentium dolorem omnis repellat saepe. Incidunt laudantium at similique nobis perferendis et illo dolor aliquid nisi voluptatum eaque ab accusamus maxime possimus, ut ratione soluta
    nam, natus quibusdam illum! Qui modi cum libero odit blanditiis distinctio eveniet illo facilis alias, aut neque perspiciatis et ipsam, hic natus? Explicabo consequuntur voluptatibus a ipsam voluptatem, deleniti at doloribus!
  </section>
  <p class="orange date"><span>12/2020</span>-<span>02/2022</span></p>

  <section class="yellow">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, aliquam blanditiis! Magnam dolorem nostrum molestias modi, ratione id quaerat adipisci dolore impedit quas voluptate recusandae nisi deleniti sed, doloremque ullam ducimus. Voluptatem aut
    praesentium magni iusto blanditiis? Doloremque, maxime necessitatibus eaque obcaecati voluptate cumque veritatis exercitationem, dolor ex beatae blanditiis.
  </section>
  <p class="yellow date"><span>11/2018</span>-<span>10/2020</span></p>

  <section class="pink">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis blanditiis repellat nulla iste illo quos, culpa sint nihil doloribus quae molestiae eaque perspiciatis reiciendis exercitationem eum minima molestias voluptatum consequatur quisquam
    asperiores obcaecati? Quas animi quis itaque molestias praesentium maiores minima. Consequuntur hic explicabo eos expedita quidem, dolorum maiores perferendis, illum quod, placeat magni! Exercitationem architecto iusto deserunt magni possimus.
  </section>
  <p class="pink date"><span>01/2018</span>-<span>11/2018</span></p>

  <section class="blue">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur minima illum, accusamus recusandae eveniet blanditiis repellendus quaerat ullam inventore eaque? Doloremque delectus quibusdam rem hic! Modi ducimus iusto perspiciatis incidunt quidem
    cum, optio, soluta id voluptatum placeat nobis quasi maxime dolorem magni pariatur cumque illum odio dolor. Dolor libero sint ea iste, autem rerum cupiditate enim aliquam? Cumque voluptatum at dolore. Veritatis, assumenda autem. Culpa facilis dolorum
    molestias voluptatum, natus, fugit fuga amet veritatis, dicta similique suscipit temporibus porro tempora?
  </section>
  <p class="blue date"><span>07/2014</span>-<span>07/2017</span></p>
  </div
```

Comment: Can you share fiddle that replicates the issue?

Comment: Please put a runnable snippet into your question (not on an external site). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: I've added a snippet

Comment: I think I found where the problem is, but not how to fix it.
It seems that with the overlap, the biggest element to use 2 rows forces those rows to have equal size, event when that created unnecessary space.
Maybe this is why is works fine with a table layout but not a grid.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hello

If you look at the screenshot of your code view with dev tools (we see the grid), it's normal you have blank space!

Try to take out the title out of the grid. Or that could also be solved with nested grid

Comment: What do you mean by "solved with nested grid" ?
Like for example, one that bothers me a lot is the big blank space below the last one (blue). It serves no purpose, it doesn't make any sense for it to be here (at least to me).

I tried the same design with a table, and it works but... Tables, ew !

Answer (score 0):

try like below,

```css
:root {
  font-size: 1px;
}

body {
  font-size: 16rem;
}


/*******/

.wrapper {
  --border-width: 0.5em;
  --gap: 8rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: var(--gap);
  padding: 0.5em;
  align-items: start;
}

h2 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  font-size: 2em;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  text-align: justify;
  border-top: var(--border-width) solid var(--accent);
  border-bottom: var(--border-width) solid transparent;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  max-width: 60ch;
}

section::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: var(--border-width);
  width: calc(var(--border-width) + var(--gap));
  background-color: var(--accent);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--border-width));
  z-index: -1;
}

section:nth-of-type(odd) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  border-right: var(--border-width) solid var(--accent);
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
}

section:nth-of-type(odd)::after {
  left: 0;
  translate: -100%;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  justify-self: end;
  border-left: var(--border-width) solid var(--accent);
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
}

section:nth-of-type(even)::after {
  right: 0;
  translate: 100%;
}

.date {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12rem;
  padding: 0.6em 0.3em;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  background-color: var(--accent);
  color: white;
  margin:0px;
}

.date:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border-radius: 1em 0 1em 0;
}

.date:nth-of-type(even) {
  border-radius: 0 1em 0 1em;
}

.date>* {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.green {
  --accent: hsl(171, 67%, 28%);
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.orange {
  --accent: hsl(22, 99%, 50%);
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.orange.date {
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.yellow {
  --accent: hsl(46, 100%, 47%);
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.yellow.date {
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.pink {
  --accent: hsl(343, 78%, 62%);
  grid-row: 4/6;
}

.pink.date {
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.blue {
  --accent: hsl(192deg 80% 48%);
  grid-row: 5/7;
}

.blue.date {
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>date wise</h2>

  <section class="green">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus quidem qui, aliquid asperiores commodi officiis inventore laboriosam dignissimos dolor officia id itaque tempora provident exercitationem accusamus expedita ullam dolorum fuga. Officiis temporibus
    porro nesciunt libero, eum aliquid doloremque minima nisi sint minus id mollitia ea quisquam consequuntur laudantium autem. Aperiam.
  </section>
  <p class="green date"><span>03/2022</span>-<span>04/2023</span></p>

  <section class="orange">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, quisquam atque. Dolores beatae, nisi, laborum perspiciatis architecto non dolorem quae, doloribus aliquam quaerat rem? Esse hic illum sint mollitia quibusdam repellendus totam dolorum voluptatem
    ipsa, nobis sapiente. Quasi quo porro aperiam cumque nobis debitis praesentium dolorem omnis repellat saepe. Incidunt laudantium at similique nobis perferendis et illo dolor aliquid nisi voluptatum eaque ab accusamus maxime possimus, ut ratione soluta
    nam, natus quibusdam illum! Qui modi cum libero odit blanditiis distinctio eveniet illo facilis alias, aut neque perspiciatis et ipsam, hic natus? Explicabo consequuntur voluptatibus a ipsam voluptatem, deleniti at doloribus!
  </section>
  <p class="orange date"><span>12/2020</span>-<span>02/2022</span></p>

  <section class="yellow">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, aliquam blanditiis! Magnam dolorem nostrum molestias modi, ratione id quaerat adipisci dolore impedit quas voluptate recusandae nisi deleniti sed, doloremque ullam ducimus. Voluptatem aut
    praesentium magni iusto blanditiis? Doloremque, maxime necessitatibus eaque obcaecati voluptate cumque veritatis exercitationem, dolor ex beatae blanditiis.
  </section>
  <p class="yellow date"><span>11/2018</span>-<span>10/2020</span></p>

  <section class="pink">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis blanditiis repellat nulla iste illo quos, culpa sint nihil doloribus quae molestiae eaque perspiciatis reiciendis exercitationem eum minima molestias voluptatum consequatur quisquam
    asperiores obcaecati? Quas animi quis itaque molestias praesentium maiores minima. Consequuntur hic explicabo eos expedita quidem, dolorum maiores perferendis, illum quod, placeat magni! Exercitationem architecto iusto deserunt magni possimus.
  </section>
  <p class="pink date"><span>01/2018</span>-<span>11/2018</span></p>

  <section class="blue">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur minima illum, accusamus recusandae eveniet blanditiis repellendus quaerat ullam inventore eaque? Doloremque delectus quibusdam rem hic! Modi ducimus iusto perspiciatis incidunt quidem
    cum, optio, soluta id voluptatum placeat nobis quasi maxime dolorem magni pariatur cumque illum odio dolor. Dolor libero sint ea iste, autem rerum cupiditate enim aliquam? Cumque voluptatum at dolore. Veritatis, assumenda autem. Culpa facilis dolorum
    molestias voluptatum, natus, fugit fuga amet veritatis, dicta similique suscipit temporibus porro tempora?
  </section>
  <p class="blue date"><span>07/2014</span>-<span>07/2017</span></p>
  </div>
```

please comment if any query

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see what you changed, and it doesn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: you want to remove date above same colour line space , is it right? try this code on new page